# Python: Extract text from Word files in a url

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the url containing a certain file, in this case a word document, read the contents of the document. I have seen several examples of how to extract text from local documents but not from a url. Would it be the same from an http address than from an ftp?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'ftp://path/to/file.docx'

txt = urlopen(url).read()
```

the value of text is:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xdd\xfc\x957f\x01\x00\x00 \x05\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 ...'
```

I try to decode

```
txt.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

but this returns `PK ...` followed by other strange characters

The option to save the document and then process it is not feasible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use urlib2 that is what it does. :) I think there is a lib3 now.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request

Comment: you can download the file from that URL using urlib2 and save it locally finally extract the data from it as you make it for local document

Comment: *"I try to decode ... but this returns `PK ...` followed by other strange characters ... What am I doing wrong?"* - You attempt to treat a non-text file as a text file. DOCX files essentially are ZIP archive files with very specific content files. Obviously you cannot read the contents by simply trying to decode the DOCX using UTF-8. What you should do instead is download the specification for DOCX, study it, and then handle the file accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I hope someone helps

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

file = urlopen(url).read()
file = BytesIO(file)
document = ZipFile(file)
content = document.read('word/document.xml')
word_obj = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8'))
text_document = word_obj.findAll('w:t')
for t in text_document:
    print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 5):

By using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt) it's very simple:

```
import requests
import docx2txt
from io import BytesIO

url = "http://url.to.file/sample.docx"
docx = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)

# extract text
text = docx2txt.process(docx)
```

Comment: it worked for me, python-docx wasn't working for file url over http