# how to get text from a downloadable .doc file without saving?

Tags: python, file, python-requests, file-extension

I'm trying to download a `.doc` file using `requests.get()` request (though I've heard about other methods - they all require saving too)

Is there any method I could use to extract the text from it (or even convert it into a `.txt` for example) straight away without saving it into a file?

I've tried passing `request.raw` into various conventors (`docx2txt.process()` for example) but I assume they all work with files, not with streams.

Comment: Whatever third-party module you're using to parse the .doc file most certainly has a way of opening file-like bytes objects, like `bytes`, `io.StringIO`, etc.

Comment: Here is a SO answer for `.docx` format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46263156/3129414 
 . Not sure about `.doc` though.

Answer (score 1):

While the script is running the memory allocation are handled by the python interpreter but if you save the content to a file the memory allocated is different. This article can be helpful to you.

Link: [article](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/#memory-management-from-hardware-to-software)